# int issue in g++/mysql/redhat

Tags: mysql, c, api, initialization

I haven't written C in quite some time and am writing an app using the MySQL C API, compiling in g++ on redhat.

So i start outputting some fields with printfs... using the oracle api, with PRO*C, which i used to use (on suse, years ago), i could select an int and output it as:

```
int some_int;
printf("%i",some_int);
```

I tried to do that with mysql ints and i got 8 random numbers displayed... i thought this was  a mysql api issue and some config issue with my server, and i wasted a few hours trying to fix it, but couldn't, and found that i could do:

```
int some_int;
printf("%s",some_int);
```

and it would print out the integer properly. Because i'm not doing computations on the values i am extracting, i thought this an okay solution.

UNTIL I TRIED TO COUNT SOME THINGS....

I did a simple:

```
int rowcount;
for([stmt]){
rowcount++;
}
printf("%i",rowcount);
```

i am getting an 8 digit random number again... i couldn't figure out what the deal is with ints on this machine.

then i realized that if i initialize the int to zero, then i get a proper number.

can someone please explain to me under what conditions you need to initialize int variables to zero? i don't recall doing this every time in my old codebase, and i didn't see it in the example that i was modeling my mysql_stmt code from...

is there something i'm missing? also, it's entirely possible i've forgotten this is required each time

thanks...

Comment: You are not displaying all of the code in this case, please attach the code you are using to select an int from the database since right now you are just printing garbage data.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't initialize your variables, there's no guarantee of a default 0/NULL/whatever value. Some compilers MIGHT initialize it to 0 for you (IIRC, MSVC++ 6.0 would be kind enough to do so), and others might not. So don't rely on it. Never use a variable without first giving it some sort of sane value.

Answer (score 1):

Only global and static values will be initialized to zero. The variables on the stack will always contain garbage value if not initialized.

```
int g_var; //This is a global varibale. So, initialized to zero
int main()
{

int s_var = 0; //This is on stack. So, you need to explicitly initialize
static int stat_var;  //This is a static variable,  So, initialized to zero
}
```

Comment: perfect! this is the difference that i was looking for... thanks so much.

Comment: to clarify, i use all globals for the bind variable at the top of the program, which lead to my fogginess on this issue... thanks

Comment: Are global variables initialized to zero on Windows?  I had a vague recollection that it was a UNIX behavior only, but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You always neet to initialize your variables. To catch this sort of error, you should probably compile with `-Wall` to give you all warnings that `g++` can provide. I also prefer to use `-Werror` to make all warnings errors, since it's almost always the case that a warning indicates an error or a potential error and that cleaning up the code is better than leaving it as is.

Also, in your second printf, you used `%s` which is for printing strings, not integers.

```
int i = 0;
printf("%d\n", i);
// or
printf("%i\n", i);
```

Is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Variable are not automatically initialized in c.

Answer (score 0):

You have indeed forgotten.  In C and C++, you don't get any automatic initialization; the contents of `c` after `int c;` are whatever happens to be at the address referred to by `c` at the time.

Best practice: initialize at the definition: `int c = 0;`.

Oh, PS, and take some care that the MySQL int type matches the C int type; I think it does but I'm not positive.  It will be, however, both architecture and compiler sensitive, since `sizeof(int)` isn't the same in all C environments.

Answer (score 0):

Uninitialized variable.

```
int some_int = 0;
```